# Stabilizer of the orthogonal group of the Minkowski form acting on the upper sheet of hyperboloid space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I was studying [this paper](http://users.jyu.fi/~parkkone/RG2012/HypGeom.pdf) and on page 8 the author defines the orthogonal group associated to the Minkowski linear form in the usual way ( $A \in O(1,n) \Longleftrightarrow \langle Ax | Ay \rangle =  \langle x|y \rangle \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{1,n}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with the Minkowski linear form). $\mathbb{H}^n$ is defined as the $x :  \langle x | x \rangle  = -1$ and $x_0 > 0$.

The part that I can't prove is that the stabilizer of $\mathbb{H}^n$ is equal to the subset of $O(1,n)$ such that the first column belongs to $\mathbb{H}^n$. I did prove that if $A \in Stab_{O(1,n)} \ \mathbb{H}^n$ then $A_0$ must belong to $\mathbb{H}^n$, but the reverse is escaping me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively speaking you have this: you know that any $A\in O(1,n)$ will map the point $x_0=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ to an element of the two-sheeted hyperboloid. It could be the upper sheet or the lower sheet. With the extra condition of $A_{00}>0$ you know it will be mapped to the upper sheet. So *one* point from the upper sheet goes to a point on the upper sheet. From this you want to conclude that *all* points on the upper sheet stay on the upper sheet.

You will need some kind of continuity argument here. Something that says that if a point $x$ stays on the upper sheet, then a point $y$ close by will stay there, too. Assume this were not the case. Then you would have a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ made of points on the upper sheet, which gets mapped to something that lies partially on the upper sheet and partially on the lower sheet. This cannot be done without a discontinuity, and linear functions are continuous.

This is just a proof idea. You may need to flesh this out to make it rigorous enough for your formalism, but it should be enough to guide your approach.